# problem in installing hydro

Tags: ros, installation, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hai,

1. I am new to linux and ROS. I am using 12.04 (32 bit) in a 64 bit machine. I tried to install ros-hydro package. After fetching (sudo apt-get install) 90-95% package, download stops by giving an error:

**unable to fetch some archives maybe run apt-get update or try with fix-missing**

Earlier, I installed same package in a 32 bit machine without any error.

2. Links that are failed to open  in terminal window are accessible through web browser in UBUNTU O.S.
3. I am accessing internet through co-axial cable modem (does n't have any proxy  settings)

Thanks,
kota

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188399/problem-in-installing-hydro/) by [jkota](https://answers.ros.org/users/19888/jkota/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-07-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's possible that you hit the repository at a bad time.

Try running `sudo apt-get update` and then retrying your installation.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-08-14**:
I've had trouble a couple times in the last week accessing all the ubuntu repositories. It's unusual but does happen sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On top of Hendrix's suggestion (meaning after you do an apt-get update)  you might also want to try this:

apt-get --download-only

in order to force Ubuntu to download all of your stuff first; No install will take place. If the operation fails here, then, yes, it is a repository error. If it succeeds, move to the regular apt-get install and check if the error happens again.

Honestly, Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 is VERY vanilla. Shouldn't fail at all.

Just in case, post you entire apt-get command, so we know what you are installing.

---

Originally posted by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) with karma: 255 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1